# How to get a list of all elements in a revit with c#

Tags: c#, revit, revit-api

I would like to add a plug in that reads in a file of data that has a string of RevitIds and paints them.

I can't figure out how to find a given element in Revit based on a string elementId using C#.

```
UIApplication uiApp = commandData.Application;
 Document doc = uiApp.ActiveUIDocument.Document;
```

I know that this gives me a document but I don;t know how to get all of the ids. I was thinking of having a foreach loop that checks the string of element id with that of all in the document until it finds a match. Then, I can manipulate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a **FilteredElementCollector** to iterate through specific element types to get their elementId's.

```
FilteredElementCollector docCollector = new FilteredElementCollector(document).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls);
```

followed by(as you suggested):

```
foreach(Element el in docCollector)
{
ElementId elID = el.Id;
//....
}
```

Modified version:

```
List<ElementId> ids = new FilteredElementCollector(document).OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls).ToElementIds().ToList();
```

followed by(as you suggested):

```
foreach(ElementId elId in ids)
{
//....
}
```

If you are thinking about iterating through ALL elements I suggest looking at this blog post from [The Building Coder: Do Not Filter For All Elements](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/06/filter-for-all-elements.html)

Comment: what you are proposing is extremely expensive - will take a lot longer than what was proposed below - and i would suggest doing what Darren suggested below.

Comment: Absolutely.  To get an element from an ElementId use the reponse below.  However, the second part of the question asked how to get all of the ElementId's.  My response showed how to get ElementId's from a specific category.

Comment: OP clearly is a noob. Now, he also explicitly states that he wants a "loop that checks the string of element id with that of all in the document until it finds a match". That doesn't require a loop. You can do what Daren suggested below and if GetElement() returns nothing that means your string id doesn't exist in the document. Just move on to next one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Document.GetElement` method to get an element by it's `ElementId`. The answer to your question depends a bit on if you have a `UniqueId` or an `ElementId` in string representation. Check here for some clarification: https://boostyourbim.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/getting-an-element-from-a-string-id/

Assuming you have an `ElementId` (not a GUID, just a number), you can do this:

```
int idInt = Convert.ToInt32(idAsString);
ElementId id = new ElementId(idInt);
Element eFromId = doc.GetElement(id);
```

Or even shorter:

```
Element element = doc.GetElement(new ElementId(Convert.ToInt32(idAsString)));
```